# Switch-case with variations in android

Tags: android

I wonder if I can turn the following chart into switch-case statement in android. I know I can do it with if-else but I just wonder if I can...
E.g-

```
switch (bodyfat)
case 2-4 : show (Essential Fat);
case 6-13 : show (Athelete Fat);
```

.......
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with switch case in the following way:

```
switch (bodyfat)
    case 2: 
    case 3:
    case 4:
        show (Essential Fat);
        break;
    case 6: 
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9: 
    case 10:
    case 11:
    case 12: 
    case 13:
        show (Athelete Fat);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you're better off sticking with an if-else statement. The equivalent for a switch case (which I don't recommend using) would be something like this:

```
switch(bodyfat) {
    case 2:
    case 3:
    case 4:
        show (Essential Fat);
        break;
    case 6:
    case 7:
    //...etc.
}
```

Then it just falls through for any of the values. You have to have a case for *every* value, though. For a range of values like this you're better off sticking with if-else.

Answer (score 1):

```
switch (bodyfat) {
case 2:
case 3:
case 4: show (Essential Fat); break;

}
```

instead of this:

```
if (bodyfat >= 2 && bodyfat =< 4) {
 show (Essential Fat);
} else if (bodyfat >= 6 && bodyfat =< 13) {
show (Athelete Fat);
}
```

you can try this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of tertiary statements for a two-outcome check:

```
IFat result = (bodyfat >= 2 && bodyfat <= 4) ? EssentialFat : AthleteFat;
show(result);
```

Assumes interfaces or subclass structure, but thought I'd include this in the discussion.